# Can I add css style to javascript elements?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm pulling a user's location and displaying it on a map with an icon I have saved. The icon I have saved is too big, so I'm trying to resize it with CSS but I'm not sure how to do that loading the svg into the js file. I'm not sure if I should load the svg file in the html document or in the js file like I have.

I tried loading the icon into the html file, give it an id, and use .getElementById to add it into the js file and then just add css styling in the css file but for some reason that didn't work. I'm not sure if I did something incorrectly doing it that way, though.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 12,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  // User Location Icon
  var userLocationIcon = 'img/SVG/User_Location.svg';

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      //Centers map to current position  
      map.setCenter(pos);

      //Sets icon to current position
      var currentLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        icon: userLocationIcon
      });

    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#map {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the `img` folder inside `js`? If not you might have to change it to `/img...`

Comment: @DigitalDouble the code above works and the icon loads well....sorry for not specifying! I would just like to add css styling to that image because it's too large and I was unsure the best way to do that

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's unsupported using the basic API as the Map is in an `iframe`, whose elements do not inherit your CSS by default.

However here's a solution I found which uses an external library.

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: myMap.getCenter(),
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 0, //tamaño 0
    },
    map: myMap,
    draggable: true,
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
    labelClass: "label", // the CSS class for the label
});
```

http://codepen.io/diana_aceves/pen/HjKdx

There's also RichMarker.

Both plugins can be found here: http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html

Unfortunately for you though, github's down.